# Finding the location of create button in Yii2

Tags: yii, yii2

I want to DELETE the create button from a view in Yii2, but I don't know where the path location
Here is the picture:

[image]

I don't know where the location of create button. Does anyone know where the location is? Thankyou in advance

NB: I just want to remove the create button from a view, not from all of views

Here is my view:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\widgets\Pjax;
use yii\bootstrap\Model;
use yii\helpers\Url;
use kartik\export\ExportMenu;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel app\models\Temppelamarmagisterjk */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = Yii::t('app', 'Pelamar Magister Berdasarkan Jenis Kelamin');
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="tempppelamarmagisterjk-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Create Jumlah Pelamar Magister'), ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p>
    <?php
        $gridColumns =[
            'TahunDaftar',
            'Lakilaki',
            'Perempuan',
            'TidakDiketahui',
            'Total'
        ];

        //Renders a export dropdown menu
        echo ExportMenu::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'columns' => $gridColumns,
            'fontAwesome' => true,
            ]);
    ?>
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

            'TahunDaftar',
            'Lakilaki',
            'Perempuan',
            'TidakDiketahui',
            'Total',

            ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: the code you provided  is not related  to the image  ... please  .. firts update your question and add the controller/action  that invoke the view you need ..

Comment: thank you for your correction. I have updated my question @scaisEdge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you provided  is not the right code for the image  anyway  your create button is

```
<p>
    <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Create Pelamar Magister'), ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
</p>
```

you could simple comment the php   (using a

```
<p>
    <?php /* echo  Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Create Pelamar Magister'), ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) */ ?>
</p>
```